friend can't access private members using namespace
I'm getting the following errors when using MS Visual Studio 2019 when overloading operator<<:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2248   'Instruction::Device_Impedance::m_minimum_ohms': cannot access private member declared in class 'Instruction::Device_Impedance' friend_ostream_namespace    device_impedance.cpp    13  
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2248   'Instruction::Device_Impedance::m_maximum_ohms': cannot access private member declared in class 'Instruction::Device_Impedance' friend_ostream_namespace    device_impedance.cpp    14  

device_impedance.hpp:
#ifndef INSTRUCTION_DEVICE_IMPEDANCE_HPP
#define INSTRUCTION_DEVICE_IMPEDANCE_HPP

#include <string>
#include <iostream>


namespace Instruction
{

class Device_Impedance
{
public:
    Device_Impedance();

    Device_Impedance(const unsigned int min_ohms,
                     const unsigned int max_ohms);
       
    //! Constructor -- Copy
    Device_Impedance(const Device_Impedance&  di);
    
    //! Destructor
    ~Device_Impedance();

public:
    Device_Impedance&
    operator=(const Device_Impedance& di);

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Instruction::Device_Impedance&   di);
   

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Public Methods
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
public:
    const std::string&      get_name() const override;
    
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Private Members
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
private:
    unsigned int    m_minimum_ohms;
    unsigned int    m_maximum_ohms;
};


}   // End namespace Instruction

/*! @}  // End Doxygen Group
 */

#endif // INSTRUCTION_DEVICE_IMPEDANCE_HPP  

device_impedance.cpp
#include "device_impedance.hpp"

using namespace Instruction;


/*!
 *  \details    Output the instruction name to the stream.
 */
std::ostream&
operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Instruction::Device_Impedance&   di)
{
        out << di.get_name()
//***** The next two lines are causing the error.
            << "    " << di.m_minimum_ohms
            << ", "   << di.m_maximum_ohms
            << "\n";

    return out;
}


const std::string&
Device_Impedance ::
get_name() const
{
    static std::string  instruction_name{"DEVICE_IMPEDANCE"};
    return instruction_name;
}

Do I have the namespace syntax correct for the implementation of operator<<?

Please post complete verbatim error messages from Build Output pane.

Can you post a [mre] and avoid visual garbage? I can't replicate the issue. getting error: 'const std::string& Instruction::Device_Impedance::get_name() const' marked 'override', but does not override

@3CxEZiVlQ:  The error messages are vebatim.  Do you want a screen snapshot?

No, your syntax is incorrect. using namespace does not cause the following declarations/definitions to inhabit that namespace.
Either use namespace Instruction { /*definition of operator<< here*/ } like you do in the header or qualify the name in the definition:
std::ostream&
Instruction::operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Instruction::Device_Impedance&   di)

(It seems that this is now intended to not be allowed anymore and GCC soft-rejects it by warning and rejecting with -pedantic-errors, see comments below.)
Otherwise you are defining the global ::operator<< overload, not the friended one that inhabits in the namespace enclosing the class, i.e. in Instruction.
What using namespace does however achieve is that you won't have to qualify names for the purpose of lookup, so e.g. Instruction:: in the function parameter is redundant with it. The same is also true in the declaration in the class.

Also, as noted in the question comments override on get_name is also wrong, because this function isn't actually an override.

The qualification, Instruction::operator<<, still produced an error.  However, placing the implementation in namespace Instruction { /*...*/} did work (no errors generated).

@Thomas Matthews -- the Standard says "A friend declaration never binds any names". I understand it, that when you declare a friend function inside a class, it does not introduce a new name in the surrounding namespace. The friend declaration is simply a declaration of intent to allow the specified function or class to access the private and protected members of the class.

@ThomasMatthews Works for me with the qualified name as well: https://godbolt.org/z/oeGYbEnWc

@user17732522 -- gcc gives a warning: https://godbolt.org/z/GrnbGnd8f I can understand why it would (or wouldn't) be an error, but why warning?

@Gene With -pedantic-errors GCC also rejects it. Intent of CWG 1477 seemed to be to allow this. CWG 1900 reraised the question and P1787R6 claims to resolve it by rejecting the example in CWG 1477. However, I haven't understood yet how P1787R6 rejects it. Anyway, Clang has not implemented that part of P1787 yet, see https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/54150.

namespace Instruction {

class Device_Impedance {
 public:
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,
                                  const Instruction::Device_Impedance& di);

 private:
  unsigned int m_minimum_ohms;
  unsigned int m_maximum_ohms;
};

}  // namespace Instruction

The above minimized class declares the friend operator<< in the namespace Instruction.
using namespace Instruction;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,
                         const Instruction::Device_Impedance& di) {
  out << di.get_name() << "    " << di.m_minimum_ohms << ", "
      << di.m_maximum_ohms << "\n";
  return out;
}

The above code defines the operator<< in the global namespace, it does not define the friend operator<< in the namespace Instruction.
The definition must be in the namespace
namespace Instruction {

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,
                         const Instruction::Device_Impedance& di) {
  out << di.get_name() << "    " << di.m_minimum_ohms << ", "
      << di.m_maximum_ohms << "\n";
  return out;
}

}  // namespace Instruction

Or in the class
namespace Instruction {

class Device_Impedance {
 public:
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,
                                  const Instruction::Device_Impedance& di) {
    out << di.get_name() << "    " << di.m_minimum_ohms << ", "
        << di.m_maximum_ohms << "\n";
    return out;
  }

 private:
  unsigned int m_minimum_ohms;
  unsigned int m_maximum_ohms;
};

}  // namespace Instruction

